# Is there a way to remove a class from a HTML element when another element is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple rock, paper scissors game where the computer generated choice will be highlighted with a coloured border which will then be returned to normal when another choice is picked. Currently I am using .classList.add() and .classList.remove() to achieve this. Is there a way to clean this code up as it feels very manual right now.

```
<script>
        function getComputerChoice() {
            // Generating Rock, Paper or Scissors
            let choices = ["Scissors", "Paper", "Rock"]
            let selection = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]

            rock = document.querySelector("#computerRock")
            paper = document.querySelector("#computerPaper")
            scissors = document.querySelector("#computerScissors")

            if (selection === "Rock") {
                rock.classList.add("computerActive")
                paper.classList.remove("computerActive")
                scissors.classList.remove("computerActive")
            }
            else if (selection === "Paper") {
                paper.classList.add("computerActive")
                rock.classList.remove("computerActive")
                scissors.classList.remove("computerActive")
            }
            else if (selection === "Scissors") {
                scissors.classList.add("computerActive")
                rock.classList.remove("computerActive")
                paper.classList.remove("computerActive")
            }

            return selection
        }
</script>

// CSS code for reference
.computerActive {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 5px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Can try this*/

function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = {
    Rock: "#computerRock",
    Paper: "#computerPaper",
    Scissors: "#computerScissors",
  };
  
  const classToAdd = "computerActive";
  const selection = Object.keys(choices)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  
  Object.values(choices).forEach(selector => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.classList.remove(classToAdd);
    if (selector === choices[selection]) {
      element.classList.add(classToAdd);
    }
  });
  
  return selection;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).